# Is it ok to use only filter query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

i have to query elastic search for some data and all my filters are drop down values as in they are exact matches only so i thought of using only the filter query and not any must or match query, so is there any problem with this kind of approach.
in the below example i am trying to get last 15 min data where L1 is any 1 of  ("XYZ","CFG") and L2 is any 1 of  ( "ABC","CDE")
My query looks like below :

```
{
"size": 20,
"sort": [
    {
        "eventTs": "desc"
    }
],
"query": {
    "bool": {
 
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "eventTs": {
                        "gte": "now-15m",
                        "lte": "now",
                        "format": "epoch_millis",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "l1": [
                        "XYZ","CFG"
                    ]
                }
            },
                {
                "terms": {
                    "l2":[
                        "ABC","CDE"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `_score` which is used to show the relevant documents according to their `score`, you can use `filter` which is executed in much faster way(since calculation of score is disabled), and cached as well.

Must read [query and filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) for in-depth understanding of these concepts.